# UIWebView delegates don't fire in a custom class

Tags: ios, swift, delegates

I spent around 5 hours searching on `StackOverFlow` about how to implement this and I still not found a solution yet!

I have created a new iOS Swift app just to explain you what exactly I am trying to resolve.

First, I have a `UIButton` on main storyboard and when you click on it, it creates a new object from class `WebViewAsPopup` which creates programmatically a new `WebView` and a background as `UIView` with alpha 0.5, add some styling and then it add them to the main view controller `ViewController` as a popup.

Secondly, I couldn't set a delegate to those `WebView's` to handle `UIWebViewDelegate` and listen to both `webViewDidStartLoad` and `webViewDidFinishLoad`

Here's my code:

`ViewController.swift`

```
//
//  ViewController.swift
//  MySimpleApp
//

import UIKit

class ViewController: UIViewController {

    @IBOutlet weak var showPopupBtn: UIButton!

    override func viewDidLoad() {
        super.viewDidLoad()

    }

    override func didReceiveMemoryWarning() {
        super.didReceiveMemoryWarning()
        // Dispose of any resources that can be recreated.
    }


    @IBAction func showPopupTapped(_ sender: Any) {
        let popup = WebViewAsPopup()
        popup.showWebViewPopup(on: self)
    }

}
```

`WebViewAsPopup.swift`

```
//
//  WebViewAsPopup.swift
//  MySimpleApp
//

import WebKit

class WebViewAsPopup: NSObject, UIWebViewDelegate {

    func showWebViewPopup(on controller: UIViewController) {
        // Popup background
        let bg = UIView()
        bg.frame = CGRect(x: 0, y: 0, width: UIScreen.main.bounds.width, height: UIScreen.main.bounds.height)
        bg.layer.backgroundColor = UIColor.black.withAlphaComponent(0.5).cgColor

        // Webview sizing
        let width = UIScreen.main.bounds.width - 60
        let height = UIScreen.main.bounds.height - 200
        let x = UIScreen.main.bounds.width/2 - width/2
        let y = UIScreen.main.bounds.height/2 - height/2

        // Webview stuff
        let webView = UIWebView()
        webView.frame = CGRect(x: x, y: y, width: width, height: height)
        let url = URL(string: "https://google.com")
        let request = URLRequest(url: url!)
        // webView.delegate = self << it crash here
        webView.loadRequest(request)

        // Styling webview popup
        webView.layer.borderWidth = 1
        webView.layer.borderColor = UIColor.black.cgColor
        webView.layer.masksToBounds = true
        webView.layer.cornerRadius = 10

        // Add bg then webview to main view controller
        controller.view.addSubview(bg)
        controller.view.addSubview(webView)
    }

    func webViewDidStartLoad(_ webView: UIWebView)
    {
        print("#webViewDidStartLoad!") // << it doesn't fire :(
    }
    func webViewDidFinishLoad(_ webView: UIWebView)
    {
        print("#webViewDidFinishLoad!") // << it doesn't fire :(
    }

}
```

Comment: I don’t know why you can’t set the WebView’s delegate, but I do know that your popup object is being discarded immediately after the button’s action method is finished.

Comment: You’ll need to save the popup object somewhere, for example as a property on your ViewController object.

Comment: Also, as an unrelated, pedantic point, `WebKit` is only needed if you're using the newer `WKWebView` objects. Legacy `UIWebView`s (as noted by the 'UI' prefix) are included in `UIKit`.

Comment: Man, I appreciate your time saving my day :)  let's discuss on your answer below..

Answer (score 2, accepted):

As I noted in my comments, you need to save the popup object somewhere in order to retain it. If not (as in your example code), then it will be deallocated as soon as the action method `showPopupTapped(_:)` is completed.

Try this:

```
import UIKit

class ViewController: UIViewController {

    @IBOutlet weak var showPopupBtn: UIButton!

    let popup = WebViewAsPopup()

    @IBAction func showPopupTapped(_ sender: Any) {
        self.popup.showWebViewPopup(on: self)
    }

}
```

Bonus Note:

If you're wondering why you don't need to do the same to the background view and web view in your popup object, that's because views automatically retain their subviews.

So, once you add your background view and web view as subviews to a parent view, their retain count goes up and will survive their current scope.

Comment: Ok, I tried that and it worked :) and as I understand, popup object will be deallocated as soon as the action method showPopupTapped(_:) is completed. Thank you so much

Comment: For you guys, to make it work and listen to delegates, please uncomment this line `webView.delegate = self` on `WebViewAsPopup.swift`

Comment: No problem! I'm glad that fixed it for you.